# Is enum a proper solution in case the original values of enum are stored in the database?

Tags: java, database, enums, factory

I am currently working on a log data rendering program. There are different types of log data such as *INPUT TEXT*, *OUTPUT TEXT*, *INTERMEDIATE TEXT* etc. and logs are stored in the database, where each row contains a corresponding *log type*.

The ways of rending log data with different *log type*s are different from each other, and thus I plan to apply the *simple factory* with an interface `TextLogger` containing several implementations such as `InputTextLogger`, `OutputTextLogger`. The factory `LoggerFactory` could look like this:

```
public class LoggerFactory {
  public TextLogger createLogger(String logTypeValue) {
    //use switch case or if condition here to return concrete instance of TextLogger
  }
}
```

An alternative is to return the `TextLogger` with an `enum` as an argument:

```
public class LoggerFactory {
  public TextLogger createLogger(LogType logType) {
    //use switch case to return concrete instance of TextLogger
  }
}
```

Using `enum` looks more maintainable. However, the values of log type are stored in the database, where we usually get `String` value directly, meaning more effort is needed in the code to convert the direct `String` value to `enum`

**Question: in this case is the use of `enum` suitable at all?**

Comment: If needed, your enum class can have a static function that can take String and return the right enum. Then, the enum can have a method to return a String representation.

Comment: *Opinion:* Since you get the log type from the database as a string, your factory should accept the string value directly, mainly to keep it simple for the code using the factory. Presumably there will be many callers of the factory, so don't require the callers to do the same common logic to resolve a log type, if you can make the factory do it for you. Stick with the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle: Don't Repeat Yourself, i.e. simplify the calling code. Now, if the factory would have been called with literal string, then an enum would be better.

Comment: @Andreas thanks a lot for your opinion :) i really appreciate it